# Only 2 cipher suites are offered by Powershell Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: windows, ssl, powershell, https

I am performing a Invoke-WebRequest to a site using Powershell. And i'm facing error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

```
PS C:\Users\admin> Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://myexternalsite.com -Proxy 'http://myproxy.com:8080'
Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
```

I did a packet capture and found that there is a Client Hello followed by a Handshake Failure. In the client hello, i only see 2 cipher suites offered by the client (powershell). These 2 ciphersuites are not supported by the server myexternalsite

```
Cipher Suites (2 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
```

Running a Get-TlsCipherSuite shows that thare many Cipher Suits available, however powershell had limited itself to 2 cipher suites.

How can i force Powershell to use the other ciphersuites?

> PS C:\Users\admin> Get-TlsCipherSuite | Format-Table Name
>
> Name
> ----                                    TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA            TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
> TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256                TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
> TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256         TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA384
> TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256

Comment: FYI: It looks like though not yet implemented, there's a request for this in pwsh: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5159